# Is it possible to use sortAppend with multiple columns and still do a multisort on a table?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin which works pretty well so far with one exception.
I want to use the sortAppend option with more than one column, but as soon as I set the option, the multisort (using the shift key) won't work any more.

I borrowed the code from a demo from the original page to test this with some code that should work.

So in the first example the table behaves exactly like expected. As soon as you sort any column, the table will be sorted by that column with an appended sort by "First Name". You can then hold down the shift key and click on any other column which enables the multisort feature and the table is sorted by the columns you selected. Nothing wrong here.

However as soon as I add another column to the sortAppend option the multisort feature won't work anymore. You can still sort by any column and the table will be sorted by the column you selected and after that by "First Name" and then by "Last Name". Everything great to this point. But if I now hold down the shift key and select another column, nothing happens.

To see what I mean, open the jsfiddle and click on the "Age" column, hold down the shift key and then click on "Total" multiple times. I would expect the order to change, but nothing happens.

Here are the corresponding examples:

```
sortAppend: [[0,0]]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ea7x/

```
sortAppend: [[0,0], [1,0]]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyK34/

Comment: I couldn't post more than two links, so here is the link to the [tablesorter plugin](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/)

Comment: That looks like a bug ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/LyK34/1/)). I've opened up [an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/523) and will work on a fix for the next update. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Gave me quite a hard time.

Comment: Ok, this issue has been resolved in the [latest version](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-append.html)! Try your demos now! :P

Comment: Looks better now but still some unexpected behaviour. Try to manually sort by First Name [shift] age. I would expect my manual sort to be still in order.

Comment: Manual sorting (using shift-click) overrides any sortAppend additions, i.e. if a column is already sorted, and also listed in the sortAppend,  the sortAppend addition is skipped.